# Can you make a custom template tag that returns a queryset? If yes, how? - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Let's make this very easy for my fellow SOians(?).

This is how normally the custom template tags work -

Template ->

```
{% block content %}

     blah blah blah

     {% custom_tag_load %}

{% endblock %}
```

The custom_tag_load is called and it returns a string. What I want to return is a queryset which I could possibly use like this ->

```
{% block content %}

     blah blah blah

     {% for x in custom_tag_load %}

          {{ x.datetime }}

     {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Note -> What I'm basically trying to do is to avoid passing the queryset through the view, and I'm not sure if I should be comfortable storing querysets in my global context.

Comment: This kinda defeats the whole point of MVC. It's an interesting question, but in general the view layer should never ever directly fetch data from the database. Still, +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: @Chris, that's really not true. You don't want to get your core objects from the db in the template, but ancillary stuff - eg a sidebar of recent posts - makes perfect sense within a template tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return anything you like from a tag, including a queryset. However, you can't use a tag inside the `for` tag - you can only use a variable there (or a variable passed through a filter). What you could do is get your tag to put the queryset into a variable in the context, and use that variable in the for loop. See the docs on [how to set a variable from a tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context) - although note that the development version [has an easier method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) for doing this.

However, you shouldn't be concerned about putting a queryset into a context processor, either. Don't forget that querysets are lazy, so no database hit will be made unless the queryset is evaluated or iterated in the template.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Why is the good stuff always in the development version?? FML

Comment: I have the same question but the answer did not help much. It is difficult to understand and the link is not working.

Comment: For the ones who couldn't understand this answer check out [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12897324/2275286) for creating context variables.

Answer (score 4):

A template tag can do whatever you want. From your pseudo code, you could accomplish what you need with an inclusion tag:

```
#my_tags.py
from django import template
from my_app.models import MyModel

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('my_template.html')
def my_custom_tag():
    things = MyModel.objects.all()
    return {'things' : things}


#my_template.html
{% if things %}
    <ul>
    {% for thing in things %}
        <li>{{ thing }}</li>    
    {% empty %}
        <li>Sorry, no things yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}


#the_view.html
{% load my_tags %}

{% my_custom_tag %}
```

Alternatively, you could write a custom tag that adds a queryset to the context. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Hey Brandon, this is exactly the kinda thing I want to avoid, I don't want the "my_template.html" to be outside of "the_view.html". Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 2):

I had these same problems recently and most of the answers here were kind of outdated, but a little digging through Django's documentation and I was able to sort it out.

Like most of the answers above, you can return basically anything using a template tag, but it all depends on how you register the template tags. So say you want to use a template tag to return a queryset to be available for any template you wish, you could register the template tag as a simple tag just like this

```
from django import template    
from blog.models import Post
from django.template.defaulttags import register

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_posts():
    return Post.objects.all()
```

Then to be able to access this in your template, you first need to load this file in your template like

```
{% load templatetagfile %}
```

And then to loop through, you need to first assign it to a variable before looping through

```
{% get_posts as posts %}
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.whatever }}
{% endfor %}
```

The first line there makes the queryset from the get_posts function available as a variable named posts which you can then loop through.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. the question is timeless, but all the other answers are dated.